# What is the purpose of the OptionalInt.isPresent field?

Tags: java

Looking at the source code for `java.util.OptionalInt`, an optional int is made of an `int value` and a `boolean isPresent`. The only way of obtaining an empty optional int is through the `OptionalInt.empty()` method which returns `OptionalInt.EMPTY`, the common instance for all empty optional ints.

If this is the case, then why is the `isPresent()` method implemented as `return isPresent` rather than `this == EMPTY` and reducing memory usage by getting rid of the `isPresent` field?

Comment: Probably would have been cleaner to use a separate subclass, like Guava did.

Comment: Six of one, half-dozen of the other.  It's an implementation choice that can go either way.

Comment: Reminder that `OptionalInt` is a value-based class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an implementation choice and the only people who can give a clear answer are the people who wrote the implementation.

But very likely it's a choice that puts readability, clarity and maintainability of code over memory micro optimizations.

It really doesn't make much sense to be worried about the space a boolean takes up in an object that wraps an int. If that space is relevant, an `OptionalInt` shouldn't be used in the first place, (or Java for that matter,) considering the object header needs at least 8 bytes (on 32 bit JVMs, more on 64 bit) already.

Java isn't for writing memory constrained applications, it's for writing easily maintainable code. And implementing `isPresent()` as getter for `isPresent` is easier to read, less error prone when refactoring and fits with established Java coding practices.

<s>*On a side note: Since Java objects are 8 byte aligned it probably doesn't even make the class smaller when you remove `isPresent`.*</s> *As [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059372/eugene) pointed out in a comment, it actually does increase the size, as the field `isPresent` lies right on the boundary and then 7 more bytes are added for padding.*

Comment: minor nitpicking: I just tested this and it turns out that `isPresent` boolean is exactly on the boundary, after it there are 7 bytes, used *just* for padding, so the class would get smaller. and when you say that each object has one header, it is correct, *but* it's *at least* 12 bytes with CompressedOOPs, which are enabled by default. Otherwise, good answer. 1+

Comment: you're right about `32 bits` (uuups!), but not for `64` it's usually the other way around, `16 bytes` is an *un-usual* one, for much larger heaps

Answer (score 3):

As stated in `OptionalInt.empty()` method's documentation:

> Though it may be tempting to do so, avoid testing if an object is empty 
>   by comparing with `==` against instances returned by `OptionalInt.empty()`.
>   There is no guarantee that it is a singleton. Instead, use `#isPresent()`.

And in fact, the following test passes:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotSame;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertSame;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.OptionalInt;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class Tests {
    @Test
    void test() {
        var empty = OptionalInt.empty();
        assertSame(empty, empty);
        var anotherEmpty = fabricateEmpty();
        assertFalse(anotherEmpty.isPresent());
        assertNotSame(empty, anotherEmpty);
    }

    private OptionalInt fabricateEmpty() {
        try {
            var constructor = OptionalInt.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            return constructor.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And while it may seem contrived, many popular frameworks use reflection or `Unsafe` to construct instances.